# How would I set a custom cursor in Java?

Tags: java, cursor

Recently I have noticed this in Java:

```
Cursor.CUSTOM_CURSOR
```

I tried:

```
setCursor(Cursor.CUSTOM_CURSOR);
```

And I get the error (probably because the custom cursor hasn't been defined):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal cursor type
```

Could anyone tell me how I would set the cursor to a custom one, and how to define the custom cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create the cursor first before setting

Cursor customCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursorImage, cursorHotSpot, "Cursor");

I found the following tutorial, see if that helps:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/39126-custom-cursors-using-java/

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom cursor you would need to use [`Toolkit#createCustomCursor(Image, Point, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29), this will return a `Cursor` which you can apply to components

This will require you to a image, preferably with transparency support, define the "hot spot" which is used to determine where the `MouseEvent` is generated, and a name for the cursor